# No detected fields in grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have a project with the opentelemetry packages that sends the logs to a opentelemetry collector which stores them in Loki. Everything seems to work fine except that there's no detected fields.

Is there any setting I could have missed?

[image: logs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, neither Grafana, nor Loki parse your JSON into labels<sup>*</sup>.

But you can do it easily yourself within the query:

```
{app="foo"} | json
```

This will parse JSON object stored in the log message into labels.

Not that names of fields will be sanitized and nested objects will be extracted:

> For instance, the pipeline `| json` will produce the following mapping:
>
> ```
> { "a.b": {c: "d"}, e: "f" }
> ```
>
> ->
>
> ```
> {a_b_c="d", e="f"}
> ```

See additional considerations regarding nested objects and label names [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#parser-expression).

Additionally, there are some additional considerations on support for arrays and simultaneous parsing and renaming of fields described [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#json).

---

<sup>*</sup> : This kind of parsing can also happen on the exporter's side, **but** [it is advised not to](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/get-started/labels/bp-labels/#use-dynamic-labels-sparingly). Such approach, especially with JSON, will lead to extreme growth of cardinality and sequential loses in performance of Loki.